# In cnosdb, why do I get different results when I query more often？

Tags: cnosdb

I downloaded the sample data from the official documentation

```
curl -o oceanic_station.txt https://dl.cnosdb.com/sample/oceanic_station.txt
```

I used `./run_cluster.sh` script to start cnosdb for the 3+2 model

Then I changed the replica of pulbic database to 2 and wrote the data

```
alter database public set replica 2;
\w oceanic_station.txt
```

Then I executed this sql frequently and found that sometimes there was a result and sometimes there was no result

```
select count(*) from air;
```

I am very confused about this situation. Does anyone know what that is? Is something wrong with my operation?

[image]